# Reduce margins around ggplot2 pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am including a pie chart in a document and the other charts are in `ggplot2`, so I'd like to use `ggplot2` to keep the charts consistent. However, the pie chart does not extend to the margins

```
dat <- structure(list(y = c(0.0714285714285714, 
                            0.0714285714285714, 
                            0.107142857142857, 
                            0.160714285714286, 
                            0.25, 
                            0.339285714285714), 
                      x = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L), 
                                    .Label = c("1 to 5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), 
                                    class = "factor")), 
                 class = "data.frame", 
                 .Names = c("y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(1), y = y, fill = factor(x))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  coord_polar(theta  = "y") + 
  theme_grey()
```

I'd be using `theme_void()`; I've used `theme_grey` to illustrate the point: the edges of the pie chart don't extend far enough in the panel. How can I make the diameter of the pie equal (or very close to) the width of the panel? Modifying `width=1` or `scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))` has no effect. The arguments to `coord_polar` don't seem to provide any clue either.

[image]

Comment: This is a good question; I haven't seen any ggplot2 pie chart that didn't have at least that much of a gap. Maybe `plot.margin`? Just FYI though, all of the statisticians and data viz experts these days are strongly, strongly recommending that no one use pie charts anymore. There have been a lot of prominent studies showing they're harder to interpret than other visuals yet convey relatively little information for the amount of space they use. Anyway, if there's an answer it's likely to be one of these http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/theme.html

Comment: Thanks for the data viz advice, but it's not a question on chart design.

Comment: Sure. That's why I commented on the theme options likely to solve your problem. I have to comment on the chart design though because I when I tried to find a solution to your problem I ran into pages saying those same things, and it's the same thing my data viz director taught us, so I thought you should know using a pie chart has become considered a mistake by the people who study this professionally.

Comment: `plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,0)` does not have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually solve your the problem but it does enlarge the area of the pie chart to approximately the initial size of the panel.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(1), y = y, fill = factor(x))) + 
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
coord_polar(theta  = "y") + 
guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA))) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      plot.margin = unit(c(-.75,-.75,-.75,-.75),"cm")
      )
```