# Remove extra space around polar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I read a lot of articles on stackoverflow but still could not figure out how to reduce the space around the polar plot in ggplot2. I've got a simple example from [R graph gallery](https://r-graph-gallery.com/128-ring-or-donut-plot.html) and added a facet_wrap column. My problem is the distance between the strip text (Label) is so far from the polar plot. Is there any way to reduce this space?

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(
    category = c("A", "B", "C"),
    ymax = c(0.1, 0.7, 1.0),
    ymin = c(0.0, 0.1, 0.7),
    facet = rep("Label", 3)
)

# Make the plot
ggplot(data, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=category)) +
    geom_rect() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette=4) +
    coord_polar(theta="y") +
    xlim(c(2, 4)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    facet_wrap(~facet)
```

Based on previous posts, I have tried the following codes but none of them work:

```
ggplot(...) + 
geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0, 1, by = 0.25), colour = "grey90", size = 0.2) +
theme(panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

Comment: The `scale_*` functions have an `expand=` argument and associated `expansion()` function. I suggest you try that approach.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the expansion approach on scale_x and scale_y but still haven't been able to reduce space between the figure and strip texts. Should I apply that to a specific scale_* function? Can you please provide more details on this? Thanks!

Comment: I see, yes, that doesn't change anything. Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38034560/3358272